# GetProcAddress() cannot convert

Tags: c++, winapi

```
WORD wOrdinal = IMAGE_ORDINAL(dwCThunk->u1.Ordinal);
if (!(lpApiLocalAddress = (LPVOID)GetProcAddress(
                hLocalLibrary,
                MAKEINTRESOURCE(wOrdinal)
)))
{
                printf_error("Error at GetProcAddress, code/msg = %s", GetLastErrorFormat());
                return FALSE;
};
sprintf_s(szApiInfo, "Ordinal %d", wOrdinal);
```

I am getting an unknown error and I am not really sure how to work it out:

> 'FARPROC GetProcAddress(HMODULE,LPCSTR)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'LPWSTR' to 'LPCSTR'

I tried `reinterpret_cast`'ing it, but it doesn't seem to work, am I doing it wrong?

Comment: `LPWSTR` expects a wide string (2b chars) and `LPCSTR` is a short string (1b chars). WinAPI has functions (i.e., `MultiByteToWideChar`) which should be used instead of casting.

Comment: [The `GetProcAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getprocaddress) seems to only exist in a non-Unicode ("ASCII" only) variant. You need to convert the Unicode wide-character string created by `MAKEINTRESOURCE` to a narrow (`char`) string.

Comment: ***I tried reinterpreting_cast it but it doesn't seem to work*** No, casting away an error about incompatible string pointers is never the solution. While the cast may make the compiler stop complaining about the problem it will not work at runtime and may crash because the types are still incompatible because no data gets converted with the cast.

Comment: _I tried reinterpret_cast'ing it, but it doesn't seem to work_ That's why you shouldn't / cannot just chuck casts at things to appease the compiler.  Instead, read up on what the *real* problem is and then solve it properly.

Comment: Even though casting types is not a so good solution, it is a swift one. Try adding `(LPCSTR)` before `MAKEINTRESOURCE`. Please let me know any other errors after adding that.

Comment: @Torrecto-MSFT wide character string cannot be simply cast to TCHAR. It's never a solution. Wide character `"Word"` would look like `"W\0o\0r\0d\0"`

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie It can be done well in Unicode.

Comment: @Torrecto-MSFT That doesn't make sense

Comment: @Torrecto-MSFT A C-style explicit conversion like that should generally be considered a red flag as doing something wrong. It's also about the same as a `reinterpret_cast`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`GetProcAddress()` expects a `const char*` string, but you are giving it a `const wchar*` string, hence the error.

This is because you are using the `TCHAR` version of the `MAKEINTRESOURCE()` macro, which returns a `const wchar_t*` when you are compiling your project for Unicode.

To fix this, you should use the `MAKEINTRESOURCEA()` macro instead, which returns a `const char*` regardless of project settings.